# C++/CLI on value struct implementing an interface that has a where t : struct constraint crashes compiler

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

Having issues implementing a interface in C++/CLI on a value type struct where one of the methods on the interface happens to have a method signature that requires ref. I have used the right syntax I believe but the complier crashes. Only way I get it to compile is by removing the where constraint. What is wrong with my syntax in C++/CLI have to be doing something wrong:

Solution TestSomething.sln:

1. Create C# class library project in solution containing a single file called Class1.cs with the contents below (A). I called the library "Blah"
2. Create C++/CLI console application in solution containing a single file called TestStruct.h with the contents below (B). I called the console project "ValueStructInterfaceIssueCppCli"
3. Build the solution it will generate the following error:

> Error 1   error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.    f:\valuestructinterfaceissuecppcli\TestStruct.h 22  1   ValueStructInterfaceIssueCppCli

In C# I have a very simple interface, This is in a C# class library project, literally just a single file.

Class1.cs (A) Contents

```
using System;

namespace Blah
{
    public interface IHoopie<T> where T : struct
    {
        void DoSomething(ref T source);
    }
}
```

then I implement this interface on a value struct in C++, easy enough:

This is in a C++/CLI console application, with a project reference to the C# class library "blah" in that same solution.

TestStruct.h (B) Contents

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;

namespace Blah
{
public value struct TestStruct : public IHoopie<TestStruct> 
{
public:
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

    virtual void DoSomething(TestStruct% source)
    {
        X = 1;
        Y = 2;
        Z = 3;
    };
};
}
```

However when I try to implement the interface in C++/CLI in VS 2010 (sp1) the complier crashes, I have also tried to compline in VS 2015 (update 3) same thing.

> Error 2   error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.    ..\valuestructinterfaceissuecppcli\TestStruct.h 22  1   ValueStructInterfaceIssueCppCli

I need to limit my interface to just value types, however just as a test I removed the where constraint in the C# interface like so and above C++ code then complies complied just fine:

```
public interface IHoopie<T> 
{
    void DoSomething(ref T source);
}
```

As another test I used a "ref struct" in C++/CLI and that also worked. For whatever reason I cannot use "where T : struct" in c# and then implement that in C++/CLI on a value struct. Just seems odd. I believe I'm using the right format in C++/CLI:

```
virtual void DoSomething(TestStruct% source)
```

The % is correct for passing value type by reference it should be just fine but I don't get why it cannot compile.

also I have some concerns about simply removing the where constraint in C#. If T happens to be a object then the syntax TestStruct% source is not correct it would have to be TestStruct%^ and when T is a int for example "%^" wont work unless I'm missing something

Update!!!

ebyRob in comments mentioned something that gave me an idea. I changed the code to use a different structure for T as follows:

TestStruct.h (B) Contents

```
public value struct SomeStruct
{
public:
    double x;
};

public value struct TestStruct : public IHoopie<SomeStruct> 
{
private:
    double last_;

public:
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

    virtual void DoSomething(SomeStruct% source)
    {
        X = 1;
        Y = 2;
        Z = 3;
    };
};
```

That fixed the complier crashing....Interesting. Need to figure this out. Will post back if this is answer. My guess (and not a good one) is that in C++/CLI it is having some issue with using the struct in the .h file as the T in its own declaration? That perhaps is what crashing the complier.

Keep in mind in C# this is completely logical. I'm saying in the struct definition, I want TestStruct to implement a method called DoSomething that takes by reference a value type of itself. In context perhaps this is one possible use case (assuming DoSomething is called Copy instead)

```
Copy(ref TestStruct source) { /* do some copying */ }
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but that's *exactly* what he did there, and this is a very good first post. Anyway, C++/CLI is bugged like hell, just report that to Microsoft, they'll ignore the bug report since C++/CLI is, well... dead, but at least you'll do the right thing.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I seriously disagree, that's not a [MCVE], even with best will.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can copy/paste his code into VS and try it right away (well, except for the fact that I'm on mobile right now). What more would you expect from a mcve?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski There's something more required: 1 Verbatim error messages compile time or runtime (if present so). 2. If its a runtime error, I want to see the exact observations from a debugging session. May be you have lower standards, but these aren't mine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well, here's an excerpt from the post: *"Error 2 error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler."* (which means it's a compiler bug). It could use some quotation markup though (which I just added).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry but I'm bugged enough to post this follow-up. Next time *please* read the post fully before demanding a mcve or whatever else from the OP. I believe high rep users have an implicit expectation of exemplarity, especially towards new users who *can* write good posts, and we don't want to scare those away, do we? By the way I *do* have high standards, to the point I'm struggling to find a question worth answering lately. </rant>

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski _"I believe high rep users have an implicit expectation of exemplarity"_ And how do these help for future researchers  that don't have these _magic crystal balls_? Please write a good answer to prove what you're demanding, or move to discuss at Meta Stack Overflow. But don't just try to blame me about my decisions here!

Comment: Guys I'm confused, What should have I added to my post?

Comment: @Maxor What I demanded along [MCVE] of course. You read that linked article, did you?

Comment: @Maxor your post already contains the requested [mcve], don't worry too much about it. But like I said, it's clearly a compiler bug, and I'm not sure there's a simple workaround.

Comment: I read that link. I'm not sure what I could have added or removed. I modified the post so that I could provide directions. Its just 2 files really Class1.cs (C# class library) and TestStruct.h (C++/CLI console app). I modified my post to explain that. Hope that helps make it qualify as Complete and verifiable.

Comment: @Maxor this line seems like a recursive definition: `public value struct TestStruct : public IHoopie<TestStruct> ` ?  Wouldn't that be invalid.  Shouldn't you be defining a different struct than what you put in your hoopie interface?

Comment: @ebyrob Google for CRTP, this is a valid construct.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski well, using a different struct inside causes the compiler *not* to fail...  Might be good to point out that's actually what's going on, not something about ref vs value types causing a problem. (I replaced teststruct with internal/external struct and it didn't crash)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. IHoopie is a generic interface I want TestStruct to implement. Its not recursive but you might be on to something with respect to C++/CLI. In C# this works fine.

Let me test this theory you have....




For example you can replace "TestStruct" with "AnyStruct" and still crash the complier.

Comment: Okay this is getting weird, I created a class implementing IHoopie<int> above the broken class and it started working (or at least not failing to compile).

Comment: Would it works (compile) if you add a forward declaration of `TestStruct` before its declaration since it seems to be a bug in the specific case where the current class is used (i.e. `IHoopie<TestStruct>`). Or would it works if you replace the value struct by a ref class (also in C# constraint)?

Comment: it does work if I change to ref struct yes. Bu then the code changes from % to %^. SO it has something to do with the case where its just a % and the interface is using the struct the interface is being implemented on. I tried forward declaration, that was a good idea thanks for that, but same result :) I have 100% confirmed this was fixed in VS 2015, works fine. Still irritating time sync as the code from the vendor I'm working in is VS 2010. To fix this I had to do some gymnastics.  Lucas was correct, some complier issue in VS 2010. no way MS will address that. I wouldn't if I were then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an IHoopie implementation above your implementation seems to avoid the compiler error.  I've no idea why.

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;

namespace Blah
{
public value struct HoopieAdapter : public IHoopie<int> {
    public: virtual void DoSomething(int% source) {}
};

public value struct TestStruct : public IHoopie<TestStruct> 
{
public:
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

    virtual void DoSomething(TestStruct% source)
    {
        X = 1;
        Y = 2;
        Z = 3;
    };
};
}
```

Comment: Thanks ebyrob...this is a much better hack than I came up with. Agree makes no sense why, but it works. This is fixed in VS 2015 as a note.

Answer (score 0):

Not really and answer but Lucas and ebyrob below in comments gave me some ideas:

Based on the findings by replacing TestStruct with int or some other struct complier no longer crashed....indicating more just some complier issue. To prove this I used 4.6.1 instead of 4.0 to see if it was fixed

> Retried the original test I noted in post. It *DOES* compile just fine on .NET 4.6.1 in C+/CLI. @Lucas -> looks like a complier bug as described. Also will not be fixed in VS 2010 obviously but what do I know. Is fixed in 4.6.1 at least.

All that being said theory here brought in by ebyrob so thanks ebyrob lead me in the other direction to look even though this is totally valid syntax as Lcuas pointed out, still got me on the path.

Thanks again all